# Reading socket API at Back-end using node.js or javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a socket based API that returns data after every few seconds what i want to do is fire an event after a value is returned(every second), as being a critical API i don't want it to run on a browser(my local machine) but on a server without any interruption.

i can easily use JavaScript for the same but issue is i don't want it to run on my local machine or use my internet for the same as a continued service.

```
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
```

This will stop if my internet stops or browser closes need a persistant solution for the problem.

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? You don't know how to persist a Node.js application?

Comment: @JeremyThille on DOM i can change any html on receiving a data but, without DOM running a continuous listener on server, it is something new for me.

Comment: What? What DOM are you talking about? You just gave some Node code. And Node doesn't have a DOM. I'm lost here

Comment: You can use cronjob to schedule it after few seconds.

Comment: @phpdroid i can use but that what's use of socket api?

Comment: Ah, no, my bad. It's client-side Socket.io code, so yeah, it runs in a browser. But it's hard to give an advice because we don't really know what you're trying to do. From what I understand, you receive a value from the DOM (how?) then emit this value (to where?) Your tags say `Node.js`, so you have a Node.js server with Socket.io, so why do you say it runs in your browser? I don't understand your setup

Comment: @JeremyThille revive value from socket api as a subscriber of that api. yes i can manipulate dom at ease, you mean to say socket cannot sun on a back-end service? or anywhere i can emulate a browser environment ?

Comment: Ok. What are you trying to do? I'm completely lost with the browser emulations to run a socket. It doesn't make sense. What is the problem and what are you trying to do?

Comment: @JeremyThille Run a continuous service to receive values from a purchased socket api 3rd party.

Comment: Still not sure I understand well, but anyway, if you want a persisting Javascript application, that's Node's job. Write the code, launch it in Node (on a server somewhere) and persist it using [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). Just do `npm i -g pm2` then `pm2 start myApp.js` and tadaaaa, a persisting Node application. Who needs a browser for that

Comment: There's nothing stopping you using Node.js to run a Socket.io client, but since there is no DOM to manipulate, you'll need to decide what you want to do instead.

Comment: @JeremyThille question is about reading a `socket api` how will you continuous read the output from it without using client side?

Comment: @Quentin can i receive contentious data from socket connection on Node.js(NOT sending but receiving) and push it in a database?

Comment: @Wishacloud — Of course. There are no shortage of database modules for Node.

Comment: I don't know, as I only have fragments of what you're trying to do. In my mind, I have a few tiny pieces, "socket" here, "DOM" there, but I don't understand what you're doing and what you're trying to build.

Comment: @JeremyThille forget everything about the question u understood just can you answer this---how to save data from socket client, without using browser?

Comment: I told you, use a Node application. Node is basically Chrome's console that runs in a terminal and that you can persist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cloud solution, Amazon Web Services would be a good option for you.
They have a free tier and you can use up to 750 hours of a t2.micro instance per month for free (whole month, 24h a day). Take a look at the details on [their page](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?nc1=f_ls)

Comment: it is not a backend service tho, what will help it to run all time on a server?